# How to connect flex with mysql?

Tags: apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update a MySql DB using Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256644/how-to-update-a-mysql-db-using-flex)

I want to connect flex with mysql

please help me

Comment: You cannot connect directly - use some server side scripts.

Comment: Actually you can if you use AS3FlexDB .This library use AMFPHP to access a MySQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either choose Flex remoting for PHP AMFPHP or use A HTTPService to connect to
php file hosted on your server with returns you Db rows.

try googling  - Connecting Flex Mysql

> http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/as3flexdb/
>
> http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Simple_MySQL_to_Flex-5561.html
>
> http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/53/1/Integrating-Flash-and-mySQL/Page1.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect directly.  See:
[How to update a MySql DB using Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256644/how-to-update-a-mysql-db-using-flex)
[Accessing mysql from Adobe flex/AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400241/accessing-mysql-from-adobe-flex-air)

Answer (score 0):

Go via a PHP script as explained [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html).

Answer (score 0):

This site (http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/as3flexdb/) has a swc and instructions on how to connect to a mysql database.  I have used it before and its pretty easy to understand.

You can grab the latest code from here http://code.google.com/p/as3flexdb/